# Python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 37: invalid start byte

Tags: python

I have a Juniper router and I am trying to automate some of my tasks using Python 3.7.1. My code is running some commands perfectly but some commands are giving errors. Following is my code

```
import paramiko

def sshConnection(ip,command):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, port=22, username='username', password='password')
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
    output = stdout.readlines()
    return output


ip = '10.1.1.1'
command = 'show interfaces descriptions | match 1000 | no-more'
output = sshConnection(ip,command)
print('\n'.join(output))
```

Following is the error I am facing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mu\Documents\Python Code\write_file - Stackoverflow.py", line 16, in <module>
    output = sshConnection(ip,command)
  File "C:\Users\Mu\Documents\Python Code\write_file - Stackoverflow.py", line 10, in sshConnection
    output = stdout.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\Mu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\file.py", line 349, in readlines
    line = self.readline()
  File "C:\Users\Mu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\file.py", line 334, in readline
    return line if self._flags & self.FLAG_BINARY else u(line)
  File "C:\Users\Mu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\py3compat.py", line 156, in u
    return s.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 37: invalid start byte
```

Other router commands such as 'show version' is working fine and showing correct output. It seems the output contains some characters that are not accepted by UTF-8 encoding. I am unable to find the solution for this problem. Please help me resolve this. Thank you.

Comment: Your remote system is not using UTF-8 as the locale. Perhaps prefix your command with `LC_ALL=C` or `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` to force the locale.

Comment: Aparently an old bug of Paramiko, see [this](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/546). There should be a way to change the encoding or better yet to get bytes, but aparently there is none. Very bad design decision. The last "[solution](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/1241/commits/5a0cd44ab6c3cedd9d6e5501cde6d9fdef62c36f)" in the linked thread is even worse as it would silently remove invalid Unicode data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because by default the `readline` method of class `BufferedFile` in Paramiko decodes as UTF-8. And there seems to be no documented way to change that.

However, Paramiko works with bytes internally. The readline method in [file.py](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/file.py) terminates with `return line if self._flags & self.FLAG_BINARY else u(line)`. So, if there is a way to set this `FLAG_BINARY`, there will be no translation. The internal `_set_mode` in the same class can set this flag. The flag is acknowledged in the [doc](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/file.html), but not the way to set it.

I have not been able to find a correct way to set flags when opening the connection, but it might be possible to set the flag afterwards. If so, `readline` will return bytes. Maybe `stdout._set_mode("rb")` before any read would just work. Note that the [starting underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name) means the function is internal/undocumented and might change without notice.

Another way would be to use `read` instead of `readline`, but you will have to deal with line endings.